# 404 error even though file exists

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

all. I am super frustrated. I have a project that I've been working on. On XAMPP,it works perfectly. However,when I deployed it to my host,(XAMPP's and the host's htdocs are identical) I get 404 errors by the script. But when I type the URL manually,the host loads it just fine. Its a weird problem..I've exhausted all options. Help! Thanks!

Comment: This is usually due to case sensitivity, check that your file names are identical, as well as that the code calling the file names are identical - specifically in terms of capitals and lower case letters.

Comment: @MarcStevenPlotz, everything is good. Still getting the 404 in the script. The URL is still working

Answer (score 0):

I have came across similar issues usually going incognito or private browsing usually solve the problem.